# How to smooth geometry with morpher?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, 3d, scenekit

How to smooth geometry with morpher attached in SceneKit or Unity 3D? I heard that average the normal of vertices will work but I have no ideal how to do it.

For example I have a rough sphere like this, How can I smooth it by changing normal of vertices?  `subdivisionLevel` doesn’t works because there are some morpher animations on it.

[image]

Comment: You should decide what technologies you want. ios and opengl, for example, contradict each other. Same goes for unity3d and scenekit.